# Screen no longer turns off in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, laptop, power-management

I don't know why, but I noticed that my LCD screen no longer turns off after the time set in the Windows Power Options panel. I have tried to turn off the screen with [Wizmo](http://www.grc.com/wizmo/wizmo.htm) and that works fine. The computer goes to sleep fine after the preset time and I don't think I have any running applications that would inhibit the power management features of Windows.

I have also tried changing my Power Plan and that has not changed anything. The screen saver is disabled as well. Any thoughts?

Comment: FWIW, I've seen the same issue with my desktop machine running Windows 7 RC.  Sometimes the screen is turned off, other times it's not.  Settings are all untouched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is caused by Google Chrome. There is already a bug report opened [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=9853&q=blank%20screen&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone).

Comment: +1 Chrome was the problem here... just turning off Chrome was all I had to do to get the monitor to power off as usual

Comment: Problem has been fixed for a while now.

Answer (score 1):

If the Power Plan is defined correctly, then the monitor should turn off when the conditions happen. You should re-verify the parameters.
However, since you also say that you have no screen saver, you might try [MonitorOffSaver](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Screensavers/MonitorOffSaver.shtml) which will do that for you without having to go thru Power Management.